# SQL Command To Get Difference Between Top Two Distinct Values

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a SQL command which returns the last two distinct values from a column.

```
select distinct value from orders order by timestamp limit 2;
```

Output:

200

100

How to get the difference(100) between these two values (200-100) using a single SQL command

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this may work but will be an inefficient way of doing so especially for a large database.

```
SELECT (select distinct value from orders order by timestamp limit 1) - (select distinct value from orders order by timestamp limit 1,1) AS DIFFERENCE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` and `min` with a subquery

```
SELECT Max(mytable.value) - Min(mytable.value) 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT value 
        FROM   orders 
        ORDER  BY timestamp 
        LIMIT  2) mytable
```